# ListViewAnimations Library

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-animation

I'm trying to use [ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/README.md) library from Niek Haarman. I'm trying to use the appearance animation with a listview that contains a xml rows. The example used in the wiki is for a row of TextViews, and I'm trying to modify it without much success.

The Code from a working example for just textviews:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getListView().setDivider(null);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();

        // Create an Animation adapter, wrapping the origional one

        SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter antAdapter = new SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter(adapter);

        // Stack another animation in from the bottom

        SwingRightInAnimationAdapter test2 = new SwingRightInAnimationAdapter(antAdapter);


        test2.setAbsListView(getListView());


        setListAdapter(test2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            adapter.add("This is row number: " + String.valueOf(i));
        }

    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <String>{

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView;
            if (tv == null){
                tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this);
            }

            tv.setText(getItem(position));

            return tv;
        }

    }

}
```

Here is a sample from my code, from a fillData method (my data is pulled from a content provider):

```
private void fillData() {

    // Pulls the fields from the database and assigns them to the columns

    String[] from = new String[] { BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ITEM,
            BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME, BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_DATE, BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_IMAGE };

    // The label for each textview
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label, R.id.pName, R.id.pDate, R.id.icon };

    //getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.bm_row, null, from,
            to, 0);

    adapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder()); // Add Viewbinder to allow the BLOB data as a picture

    // ADDED THIS ---- >>>>
    SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter antAdapter = new SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter(adapter);

    // ADDED THIS
    getListView().setAdapter(antAdapter);

    // ADDED THIS ----- >>>>
    setListAdapter(antAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

This is the error message I get:

```
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call setListView() on this AnimationAdapter before setAdapter()!
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at com.haarman.listviewanimations.swinginadapters.AnimationAdapter.getView(AnimationAdapter.java:121)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-10 21:17:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

the adapter.add() method is a custom method for the arrayadapter present in the library,import the array adapter from the library(com.haarman.listviewanimations.ArrayAdapter) to use this method and make sure you pass a list of the elements or an empty list in your case to the constructor